# How to implement @property(class, readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSArray<NSString *> * _Nullable readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying implement `NSItemProviderReading` protocol.
In Objective-C, how do you satisfy:

```
@property(class, readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSArray<NSString *> * _Nullable readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;
```

I assume it wants `NSArray` with UTI, but the `class` reference is throwing me off.

Answer (score 7):

It's a `class` property, therefore we will start with `+`. It returns an `NSArray *`, the name is `readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider`. Therefore the getter will be:

```
+ (NSArray<NSString *> * _Nullable)readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider {
    return @[@"id1", @"id2"];
}
```

It's a `readonly` property, therefore we don't need a setter.

Comment: What types can be used?