# Class does not conform to NSItemProviderWriting protocol - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

Created a class that implements NSItemProviderWriting

It gives warning as:

> 1.Class 'DraggableEvent' does not conform to protocol 'NSItemProviderWriting'
>   2.Class property 'writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider' requires method 'writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider' to be defined - use @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

code:DraggableEvent.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DraggableEvent : NSObject <NSItemProviderWriting>
{

}
```

DraggableEvent.m
    @implementation DraggableEvent

```
@synthesize writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;

-(void)setWritableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider:
(NSArray*)writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider{

 }
 -(NSArray*)writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider{
   writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider = [[NSArray 
   alloc]initWithObjects:@"com.apple.ical.ics", nil];
   return writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;
  }


  - (nullable NSProgress *)loadDataWithTypeIdentifier:(NSString 
  *)typeIdentifier
               forItemProviderCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData * 
   _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error))completionHandler{
    completionHandler([self createVEvent], nil);
    return nil;
   }
```

Comment: I run into this too, Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I figure this out.

notice this, the property is a class property.

`@property (class, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;`

so we should use

`+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *)readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;`

instead of -

see this question below

[How to implement @property(class, readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSArray<NSString *> * _Nullable readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863932/how-to-implement-propertyclass-readonly-copy-nonatomic-nsarraynsstring)